# Pivot data with values from different columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, pivot, tidyr

Apologies if I'm double-posting but I have tried different things I've seen in stackoverflow & can't quite solve the issue or understand why I'm having it.

So I have a dataset like this:

```
council_name <- c("Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barnet","Barnet")
period <- c("1st 2006", "1st 2006", "1st 2006", "1st 2006", "2nd 2006", "2nd 2006", "2nd 2006", "2nd 2006", "1st 2006", "1st 2006") 
category <- c ("glass", "fridges", "paper", "glass", "glass", "fridges", "paper", "glass", "glass", "fridges")
data <- c(333, 222, 100, 98, 450, 540, 33, 450, 560, 120)
category2 <- c ("collected", "collected", "collected", "no donors", "collected", "collected", "collected", "no donors", "collected", "collected")
df <- data.frame (council_name, period, category, category2, data)
```

And what I want is something like this:

```
council_name <- c("Barking and Dagenham","Barking and Dagenham","Barnet")
period <- c("1st 2006", "2nd 2006", "1st 2006") 
glass <- c(333, 450, 560)
fridges <- c(222,540,120)
paper <- c(100, 33, NA)
no.donors <- c(98, 450, NA)
df.desired <- data.frame (council_name, period, glass, fridges, paper, no.donors)
```

I've been trying multiple things with pivot functions but the fact that I need to extract column names from both category1 and category2 but filling cells with values from the same column in df is giving me all sorts of problems.

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 2):

The following approach is a data.table one:

with your data:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

df[, sum(data), by = .(council_name, period, category, category2)][, dcast(.SD, council_name + period ~ category + category2, value.var = "V1")]
```

Which will produce

```
df
           council_name   period fridges_collected glass_collected glass_no donors paper_collected
1: Barking and Dagenham 1st 2006               222             333              98             100
2: Barking and Dagenham 2nd 2006               540             450             450              33
3:               Barnet 1st 2006               120             560              NA              NA
```

That is essentially your data, except by the differences on names and column order. Those can be fixed with data.table's `setnames` and `setcolorder`.

### What is in there:

- `sum(data), by = .(council_name...` will totalize your data for each unique combination of council, period, category and category2. Please consider running just this bit to see the output: `df[, sum(data), by = .(council_name, period, category, category2)]`
- The second part, `[, dcast(.SD, council_name + period ~ category + category2, value.var = V1)]` converts the long table that resulted before into a wide one (the format you want). It's saying that it wants council name and period in the rows and category and category2 in the columns, and that the value variable is V1 (V1 is a dummy name given in the first chained command, because I just wrote `sum(data)`, without giving it a name).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick question: in the 2nd part I get the following error "Error in valnames %chin% varnames : x is type 'double' (must be 'character' or NULL)", to which variable would this be refering to?sorry, not really used to using data.table

Comment: You can use `fun.aggregate = sum` to do it all within the `dcast` step: `dcast(df, council_name + period ~ category + category2, value.var = 'data', fun.aggregate = sum)` (actually in this specific example you don't even need `fun.aggregate = sum`, but in general I think adding that argument will make the output the same as the code in your answer)

Comment: @AntVal I missed some quotes around V1 in the last part of it. Please see my edit

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution using `pivot_wider` to transform your data into a wide format and then use `rename` to change the column names.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  # Pivot from long to wide format using the first two columns as id cols and using both category and category2 columns to get the new column names
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(council_name,period),
              names_from = c(category, category2),
              values_from = data) %>%
  # Rename the columns
  rename("glass" = "glass_collected",
         "fridges" = "fridges_collected",
         "paper" = "paper_collected",
         "no.donors" = "glass_no donors")

# A tibble: 3 x 6
# council_name         period   glass fridges paper no.donors
# <fct>                <fct>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1 Barking and Dagenham 1st 2006   333     222   100        98
# 2 Barking and Dagenham 2nd 2006   450     540    33       450
# 3 Barnet               1st 2006   560     120    NA        NA
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan V. Solórzano. It doesn't quite get me what I want because multiple cells have more than one value for data, which doesn't make much sense because in the original dataset each "Data" cell has a unique value when combining the id_cols.
I get this error: Values in `Data` are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list(Data = list)` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = list(Data = length)` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = list(Data = summary_fun)` to summarise duplicates

Comment: You could add `values_fn = list(data = length)` as an argument to `pivot_wider` to identify where the duplicates occur and check if they have sense or not. Using this option, duplicated entries should have a 2 value. If you want to stay with the duplicated entries you could add `values_fn = list(data = list)` to `pivot_wider` and then `unnest` the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another data.table approach with aggregation inside `dcast`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

dcast(df, council_name + period ~ category + category2, value.var = "data", fun.aggregate = sum)
#            council_name   period fridges_collected glass_collected glass_no donors paper_collected
# 1: Barking and Dagenham 1st 2006               222             333              98             100
# 2: Barking and Dagenham 2nd 2006               540             450             450              33
# 3:               Barnet 1st 2006               120             560               0               0
```

Answer (score 0):

At this situation you can use the `spread()` function. The code looks like:

```
spread(data=df, key=category, value=data)
```

Comment: There's 2 categories so that doesnt work. But thanks